# Why / when does $.inArray return -1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I was wondering why / when `-1` is used in JavaScript or jQuery, respectively.

I'm using this snippet:

```
if ($.inArray('false', answers) > -1) {
  window.console.log('you Lose!');
}
```

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Maybe because array index starts from `0` in javascript.

Comment: Have you read the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `-1` is returned if the expression you are looking for is not in the array you are looking in.

While, according to [its documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), `$.inArray` returns the index of the element (if it was found), an index of `-1` is impossible: This is due to the fact that indices start with 0 as lowest possible value.

Hence `-1` does just mean a non-valid index position, i.e. not found.

So, in your snippet, the test for `> -1` means: Check whether *any* valid index was found, or in other words, check whether the given value was in the array.

This is even mentioned in the documentation:

> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: PS: If it helps it would be great if you could accept this answer as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because indexes is starting with 0. (0-index).

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

alert( arr[0] ) // a;
```

So when checking the index of an element in an array (`$.inArray` and `[].indexOf`) it would be wrong to return 0 if the element isn't present:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

alert( arr.indexOf('a') ); // 0
alert( arr.indexOf('b') ); // 1
alert( arr.indexOf('c') ); // 1
alert( arr.indexOf('d') ); // -1
```

---

I would say that jQuery have a design flaw here, I would rather think that `jQuery.inArray` would return a boolean (`true/false`).